# Multiplying two dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, vb6, dimensional

how to multiply two dimensional a(5,3) and b (3,5)
so the arry c( , )= a(5,3) and b (3,5)
the first row of arry a * the columns of arry b then
the second row of arry a * the columns of arry b then

**[EDIT]** *the code of your comment:*

```
Dim arry1(5, 3) As Integer 
Dim arry2(3, 5) As Integer 
Dim i, j As Integer 
For i = 1 To 5 
  For j = 1 To 3 
    arry1(i, j) = Int(9 * Rnd + 1) 
  Next i, j 
For i = 1 To 3 
  For j = 1 To 5 
    arry2(i, j) = Int(9 * Rnd + 1) 
  Next i, j
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried already

Comment: @rob i didnt try to multiply but cuz i stop at this point

Comment: Dim arry1(5, 3) As Integer
Dim arry2(3, 5) As Integer
Dim i, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
For j = 1 To 3
arry1(i, j) = Int(9 * Rnd + 1)
Next i, j
For i = 1 To 3
For j = 1 To 5
arry2(i, j) = Int(9 * Rnd + 1)
Next i, j

Comment: please edit your original post to include the code you already have ... the code you posted in the comment above does nothing except filling the arrays with random values (if the errors are corrected) .. there is no mutliplication in your code above

Comment: your question seems like homework of a math class ... we wont be doing your homework for you, but we can help you fix errors in the code which you already made/tried

Comment: am sorry gaiz its my first post :D

Comment: @Hrqls no my frind its not dont think bad abut me :)

Comment: @Kazem : I know it was your first post, that's why I helped you with the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a, b As Integer
Dim arry1(5, 3) As Integer
Dim arry2(3, 5) As Integer
ReDim c(5, 5) As Integer
Dim i, j, s As Integer

Print ""
Print Space(15); "the first arry"
Print ""
For i = 1 To 5
  For j = 1 To 3
   arry1(i, j) = Int(9 * Rnd + 1)
   Print Space(3); arry1(i, j);
  Next j
 Print ""
Next i
Print ""
Print Space(15); " the second arry"
Print ""
For i = 1 To 3
  For j = 1 To 5
   arry2(i, j) = Int(9 * Rnd + 1)
   Print Space(3); arry2(i, j);
  Next j
 Print ""
Next i
Print ""
Print Space(15); " the result"
Print ""
cmd1.Visible = False

For a = 1 To 5
   For b = 1 To 5
      For j = 1 To 3
      s = s + (arry1(b, j) * arry2(j, a))
      c(a, b) = s
     Next j
       s=0
  Next b
Next a

For i = 1 To 5
   For j = 1 To 5
    Print Space(3); c(i, j);
   Next j
  Print ""
Next i
```

thank you for your answers i solved the problem by may self and its pleasure me if you tel your openion in my code ... thank you

Comment: I will post my comments as an answer below as I cant use any formatting in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Congrats! it works :)

Some comments:

- when you use `Dim a, b As Integer` then b will be an Integer, but a will be a Variant. It is better to use `Dim a As Integer, b As Integer` so that both a and b will be Integers
- why do you `ReDim c(5, 5) As Integer` ? You can use `Dim c(5, 5) As Integer`
- Instead of printing to the form I would show the data in a textbox or label control

Comment: thank you 
i can use dim but i prefer use redim in result array 
thank you very much for this the advice i will separate  the declaration 
but i detect an error in the program >>
the variable s still save the old summation so it is add the old result to the next result in the next element of the result array [c]
so we should equal it to zero in next loop 
it will become like this
**next j**
**s=0**
to void summing the old result with the next result
so i will edit the program

Comment: why do you prefer to use redim for the result array? ... and if redim seems better to you, then why dont you use it for the first 2 arrays as well?